# Como é que faço para fazer upload da imagem neste caso

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Cada vez que tento fazer o upload da imagem seja pelo disco ou por um link na internet obtenho, erro na linha onde está a instrução do `find_elemento`.

Peço que alguém tente fazer upload para este site em concreto e me diga como conseguiu realizar o upload da imagem com sucesso.

Está aqui o meu código:

```
def upload():
    driver.get('https://www.custojusto.pt/ai/form/0')
    #time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_name('image').send_keys("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pzTMUV7AL._SY300_.jpg")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    upload()
```